# count rows in table with many different parameters

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I know that I can count how many rows have a certain string in the columns of my table like this...

```
  $timeOfClass="W-7PM-A";
  $inclass101 = $db->prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM students WHERE timeOfClass =?");
  $inclass101->execute(array($timeOfClass));
  $inclass101rows = $inclass101->fetchColumn(0);
```

`$inClass101rows` reflects the number of rows in my database with `$timeOfClass` as `W-7PM-A`.

But how can I do this for multiple variables of the `$timeOfClass` string without writing multiple SQL statements? I have a lot of them. Would this be something like make an array of SQL statements and then run them through a while loop of `fetchColumn(0)` ?

Comment: Example: `WHERE timeOfClass IN ('W-7PM-A', 'W-7PM-B', 'W-7PM-C');` (using `IN`) then the array.

Comment: If what you're asking is "how can I have a variable length array and pass it into a prepared statement" the answer is you can't without jumping through some hoops. but look around for "array" and "prepared statement" and pdo and you should see some approaches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

// $timesOfClasses is an array in the form:
$timesOfClass = array(
    "W-7PM-A",
    "X-8AM-Y",
    "...",
);


// Generate the IN clause safely for usage with prepared statements
$params = substr(str_repeat("?,", count($timesOfClass)), 0, -1);

$inclass101 = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `students` WHERE `timeOfClass` IN({$params})");
$inclass101->execute($timesOfClass);
$inclass101rows = $inclass101->fetchColumn(0);
```

Use SQL to alter the result as you which, e.g. add a `GROUP BY` clause to get several counts for looping.

Comment: Looks great! How do I separate the results to find the how many instances of each string in the table though?

Comment: I don't know how your database abstraction works, but you can add `GROUP BY timeOfClass` to your SQL query and iterate with a loop over the result, it will give you the count for each time of class.

Answer (score 0):

`where timeofclass in ("value 1, 'value 2');` is the right sql syntax. You can take your array of times and create the in clause and concatenate it onto the end of your statement. you could also create a stored proc that handles the query and takes a CSV of values as a parameter.
HTH

Comment: You have a double quote where it should be a single & missing a single quote. `("value 1, 'value 2')` - Rewrite `('value 1', 'value 2')`

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do this for several values of $timeOfClass?

You could put all of the $timeOfClass variables in an array (W-7PM-A,W-8PM-A,etc..) then use an sql like this:

SELECT count(*) 
FROM students 
WHERE timeOfClass IN ('W-7PM-A','W-8PM-A',...)
GROUP BY timeOfClass

This would give you one SQL query that you can loop through the rows to get the individual counts.