# find value in string from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i am new in php, so i need help with this:

i have a values cell like 1,2,3,4,5

For example i need to check if value 3 is in that cell.

So, here is my code:

```
$article = $db->query("SELECT users FROM products WHERE id = $product_id");
while ($data = $article->fetch_object()) {
$users = $data->users;
}

$number_that_i_need_to_check_if_is_in_string = 3;
$users = explode(',',$users);
foreach ($users as $specific) {
    //i dont know what to do here...
}
```

And i dont know how to check is that number 3 in that string...

thx in advance.

Comment: Maybe i'm getting your question wrong, but why not using where in your query or like?

Comment: the proper solution is to normalize your table design which makes the question moot.

Comment: `WHERE column_to_check IN ('value 1', 'value 2');` something like that.

Comment: @MIIB Can you tell me how to use query for that?

Comment: Look at Fred ii comment

Comment: @MarcB can you explain what you mean with normalize? Thx.

Comment: @Fred-ii- but i have 2,3,4,5 in same row, i am not sure that i can do with IN or i can? :)

Comment: [`This answer`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21689730/) may also shed some light on the subject.

Comment: You sure can, just add to the array.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the foreach loop.  Once you have all the values in an array you can just use the in_array() function:
https://www.php.net/in_array

Also there is a problem with your while loop.  If there are multiple rows returned the way you have it written will just overwrite each value with the next so $users will only hold one value and you wont be able to explode it.

What you could do is just read all the values directly into an array by changing that line to the following:

```
$users[] = $data->users;
```

then

```
if(in_array(3,$users)){
    .....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using your code, you can do this

```
foreach($users as $specific) {
  if($number_that_i_need_to_check_if_is_in_string == $specific) {
    //do something here.
  }
}
```

There are much better ways of doing this, including writing the query to do the search for you, or using `array_search`.

Comment: i tried that, but never match, because $number_that_i_need_to_check_if_is_in_string is not number 3 it become 33, or 333 depend how many times foreach go

Answer (score 0):

You can use FIND_IN_SET mysql function like this

```
$article = $db->query("SELECT users FROM products WHERE id = $product_id AND FIND_IN_SET(3, users)");
```

This query will get you all the rows where `id=$product_id` and `users` field has 3 in it.

Comment: if you're searching for 1 FIND_IN_SET will find 1 not 11 and 111

Comment: try `select find_in_set(3, '33,3333,3');` it will return `3` which is the position of the number `3` and try `select find_in_set(3, '33,3333');` it will return 0 cause no `3` was found

Answer (score 0):

You could either include it in the query

```
SELECT users FROM products WHERE id=$product_id AND FIELD_IM_CHECKING=$number_that_i_need_to_check_if_is_in_string
```

or...

use the string you're looking for as an index for an array.

```
while($data=$article->fetch_object()){
 $users[$data->FIELD_IM_CHECKING][]=$data->users;
```

You end up with an array with the value you're looking for as the index. So $users[3] would be all users with '3' in the field you're looking for...

please do make a little better question next time. Since you're not specific in the data you have and query my answer seems pretty vague as well...